# Load images from database, problem displaying them

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

In my view i have a image tag that looks like this:

`<img src='@Url.Action( "Image", "Home", new { Id = @Id })'/>`

This calls my method in my controller that looks like this:

```
    public string Image(int Id)
    {
        string strBase64 = "";
        using (SqlConnection con = OpenConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageById", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Id",
                Value = Id
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);

            byte[] bytes = (byte[]) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            strBase64 = "data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }
        return strBase64;
    }
```

This successfully returns my base64 image, but the image is not showing in the view. If i go to the www.url?Id=234 I see my base64 string,

[image]

So i tried to return that as a image instead like this:

```
return "<img src=strBase64/>;
```

[image]

And that of course works. But how can i display the image directly when calling `<img src='@Url.Action( "Image", "Home", new { Id = @Id })'/>` from the view?
The only thing I see is "error" image.

Comment: What does the img tag look like if you inspect it in the browser when it fails to load? does `Url.Action` render an image tag that looks like `<img src=strBase64/>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return it as an actual picture all that had to be done was to change the return type to `FileStreamResult`

```
public FileStreamResult Hero()
{
    byte[] imageData = heroImage.GetHeroImage(1);
    return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is really JFIF.  I found the letters in the header JFIF.  See code below

```
            string input = "4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASAB0";
            byte[] png = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

            string mode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(png.Skip(3).Take(4).ToArray());
```